# Clone form, add new each one

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, clone

I need to add one by one form when I click the button, but in the second click the function appends more than one form.

What am I doing wrong in my script?

Thanks

```js
$('.add-more-btn').click(function() {
  var clone = $('.form-main').clone('.form-block');
   var   block = $('.form-block')
  $(block).append(clone);
});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <title>Clone forms</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <form class="form-main">
      <div class="form-block">
        <div class="form-group">
          Name
        <input type="text" name="name[]" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          Email
        <input type="text" name="email[]" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <hr>
      </div>
    </form>
    <a class="btn btn-primary add-more-btn">Add one</a>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The `clone` function is matching all the elements with the class `.form-main`. So the second time it adds 2 and the third time it adds 4 and so on.

Comment: `.clone()` [only accepts a Boolean](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) so `.clone('.form-block')` is wrong

Comment: Thanks for everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to duplicate the `.form-block` and append it to the `<form>`...
So identify the elements correctly first... The form and the element to be cloned.

Then, [`.clone()`](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) from a stored "template" on click.

Notice that you have to clone for the "template"... And again on click!

```js
var template = $(".form-block").clone();
var form = $(".form-main");

$('.add-more-btn').on('click',function() {
   var newFormBlock = template.clone(); // Clone again here, to be able to append more than once.
   form.append(newFormBlock);
});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <title>Clone forms</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <form class="form-main">
      <div class="form-block">
        <div class="form-group">
          Name
        <input type="text" name="name[]" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          Email
        <input type="text" name="email[]" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <hr>
      </div>
    </form>
    <a class="btn btn-primary add-more-btn">Add one</a>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not clone on button click. It is cloning what is in the form at the time of click which is increasing with every click.
Instead, clone the form on load and store it in a variable.
Then use it as many times.

```
var clone = $('.form-block').clone();
$('.add-more-btn').click(function() {
  $('.form-main').append(clone);
});
```

And note that .clone() does not take the parameter you were passing.

Comment: That will append the cloned element once... Then only "move" it. The `.clone()` method has to be invoked on click.

Comment: And the `<form>` element (`.form-main`) is being cloned (It's the parent here). It will produce a nested `<form>`, which is invalid.

Comment: thanks @LouysPatriceBessette I have updated the code to select the form block and append to form.

Comment: Thanks to everyone

Answer (score 1):

Another solution with `html` which copy the first set of element.

```js
var clone = $('.form-main').html();
$('.add-more-btn').click(function() {
  $('.form-main').append(clone);
});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <title>Clone forms</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <form class="form-main">
      <div class="form-block">
        <div class="form-group">
          Name
        <input type="text" name="name[]" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          Email
        <input type="text" name="email[]" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <hr>
      </div>
    </form>
    <a class="btn btn-primary add-more-btn">Add one</a>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because using the clone method on a css class every div container with the css class `.form-block` is cloned. As you add another block with the css class `.form-block` you 've got two blocks with the same class name. On the next click you clone two items and so on.

Why not using the HTML5 template tag. Using this native type of templating you can archive several advantages. Your form will be faster, because you don 't need to load the jQuery library. With a few lines of native JavaScript you can archive, what you want. Have a look at the following example.

```
<form id="my-form" action="" method="post">

</form>
<button id="add-button">Add</button>
<template id="my-template">
    <div>
        <label>
            <span>Name</span>
            <input type="text" name="name[]" placeholder="your name">
        </label>
    </div>
</template>
```

This is an html example so far. You can add your own input elements and styles here. This piece of code is just for example purposes.

Now it 's time for some native JavaScript.

```
<script>
    document.getElementById('add-button').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        var form = document.getElementById('my-form'),
            template = document.getElementById('my-template'),
            clone = document.importNode(template.content, true);

        form.appendChild(clone);
    }, false);

    // to add the first input element automatically
    var event = new Event('click');
    document.getElementById('add-button').dispatchEvent(event);
</script>
```

This works on every modern browser. For more detals about the html5 template tag and its functionality have a look at the [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template). Also have a look at [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/#feat=template) to see the browser support. As you can see, Microsofts Internet Explorer 11 does not support the template tag and its functionality. For that there are some astounding polyfills like the [Web Components small template polyfill](https://github.com/webcomponents/template) you could use, when IE11 support is in need.