# how to clone div bassed select option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have select option with count of numbers so i need now when user choose any number clone div tag personal information by this number ex: - select 8 clone 8 time ..

i try do that by use( for loop )but i have problem when run i see clone over this number ex:- choose 8 clone 16 time

this is html code and my try js code

```js
$('#c3').change(function() {
  $('.cloneHere').empty();

  var count = $('#c3').val();
  for (i = 1; count > i; i++) {
    var clone = $('.rowClone').clone();

    $('.cloneHere').append(clone);


  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='col-xs-3'>
  <label for="">count of person</label>
  <select class='form-control select2' name="" id="c3">
    <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Choose here</option>
     <option value="1">1</option>
     <option value="2">2</option>
     <option value="3">3</option>
     <option value="4">4</option>
     <option value="5">5</option>
     <option value="6">6</option>
     <option value="7">7</option>
  </select>
</div>
</div>




</div>
</div>


</div>

</div>


<div class='col-md-12'>
  <div class='box box-primary'>
    <div class='box-header with-border'>
      <h3 class='box-title'>Information of Person</h3>
    </div>

    <div class='form-group'>
      <div class='box-body rowClone2'>
        <div class=' row'>
          <div class=' col-sm-3'><label for="">Person 1</label></div>
        </div>
        <div class='row rowClone'>

          <div class='col-xs-6 col-md-3'>
            <input type="text" class="form-control">
          </div>
          <div class='col-xs-6 col-md-3'>

            <input type="text" class="form-control">
          </div>

          <div class='col-xs-6 col-md-3'>

            <input type="tel" class="form-control">
          </div>

          <div class='col-xs-6 col-md-3'>

            <input type="text" class="form-control">
          </div>


        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="row cloneHere">


        </div>


      </div>
```

Comment: Your html is very broken, alot of ending div-tags and on the other hand missing some too. Your selector .rowClone will select more elements every iteration since the cloned element also has this css-class.

Comment: because i copy from long code

Comment: Possible duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55268627/clone-form-add-new-each-one/55268854#55268854

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you are facing comes from this line: `var clone = $('.rowClone').clone();`

the first clone is fine because only 1 `.rowClone` exist, next time multiple `.rowClone` exist and it appends all of those.

You have 2 solutions, either use `var clone = $('.rowClone:first').clone();` or move `var clone = $('.rowClone').clone();` before your `for loop`

**Demo of the problem, run it and look at the console**

```js
$('#c3').change(function() {
  $('.cloneHere').empty();

  var count = $('#c3').val();
  for (i = 1; count > i; i++) {
    console.log("Number of .rowClone that exist = " + $('.rowClone').length)
    var clone = $('.rowClone').clone();
    $('.cloneHere').append(clone);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='col-xs-3'>
  <label for="">count of person</label>
  <select class='form-control select2' name="" id="c3">
    <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Choose here</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>

  </select>
</div>


<div class='col-md-12'>
  <div class='box box-primary'>
    <div class='box-header with-border'>
      <h3 class='box-title'>Information of Person</h3>
    </div>

    <div class='form-group'>
      <div class='box-body rowClone2'>
        <div class=' row'>
          <div class=' col-sm-3'><label for="">Person 1</label></div>
        </div>
        <div class='row rowClone'>

          <div class='col-xs-6 col-md-3'>
            <input type="text" class="form-control">
          </div>
          <div class='col-xs-6 col-md-3'>

            <input type="text" class="form-control">
          </div>

          <div class='col-xs-6 col-md-3'>

            <input type="tel" class="form-control">
          </div>

          <div class='col-xs-6 col-md-3'>

            <input type="text" class="form-control">
          </div>


        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="row cloneHere">


        </div>


      </div>

    </div>


  </div>

</div>
```